# Selenium chromedriver that does not depend on current Chrome installation

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, windows-server-2016

Due to organization policy, the Chrome browser installation on my Windows Server machine is automatically updated. I have some processes that rely on python Selenium and chromedriver. Because of this, my process breaks whenever my org decides to push out an update.

Is it possible to have chromedriver depend on some binary other than Chrome browser that will not be managed by my organization so that this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

Few of the workarounds to resolve the issue:

1. We have kept the chrome exe file in an artifactory and we download and install that particular chrome version every time before our execution through automation (our requirement is like that).
2. As @Corey is suggesting you can webdrivermanager, PFB link for more details
   https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager
3. You can try Dockerized Selenium, there you'll have the control in the docker-compose.yml file.